Debezium for Postgresql (Read-only)
I am currently researching methods to set up Debezium for PostgreSQL read replicas. My goal is to reduce the load on the primary database, which is crucial for my project. Unfortunately, I've noticed in the Debezium documentation that they don't support read-only databases.
I'm wondering if there are any solutions or alternative tools that can help me achieve this goal.
enter image description here
Debezium can connect and cdc for read-only databases!

Logical replication?

@Vérace Thanks you, can you explain in detail?

Not sure what's happening with your setup. Please go into great detail about it in the question.

@Vérace Hi, i sents my links about architect that i want to use. Can you check above?
I need to setup with this architecture, but Debezium say they cant't link

If you are running PG16, it might be possible as with this update of PG, WAL changes are streaming to replicas also.
In theory, you could be able to use Debezium and connect to the replica and start streaming from there, tho, not sure if doable. Never tested it.

@TudorPlugaru Thanks you, I'll keep that case in mind

Assuming that the read-only datatbase is a standby replica, the reason that Debezium didn’t support read-only databases was a limitation of PostgreSQL. Before PostgreSQL version 16, read replicas did not support logical replication. Debezium requires logical replication functionality to work for PostgreSQL.
If you’re using PostgreSQL version 16 or can upgrade to it, you can create a read-only replica that supports logical replication.
The other limitations for read-only database support was the requirement that Debezium track snapshot information in a database table.  In Debezium 2.7 that limitation resolved. With 2.7 you can now set a property to let Debezium know that your database is read-only. It will use another method for tracking incremental snapshots.
Debezium 2.7 release: https://debezium.io/blog/2024/07/01/debezium-2-7-final-released/#new-features-postgres
PostgreSQL 16 release: https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/postgresql-16-released-2715/#:~:text=September%2014%2C%202023%20%2D%20The%20PostgreSQL,data%20loading%2C%20and%20logical%20replication.

Link only answers are considered very low quality and can get deleted, please put the important parts from the linked resource into the answer body.
